# "Unable to access "128 GB Volume"" "Error mounting/dev/sdc1 at/media/whooth2/3435-3234:unknown filesystem type 'exfat' "

Tags: package-management, mount, dependencies

I am trying to copy a micro sd (which was formatted by my mavic mini drone) mounted on a sd reader, and transfer the videos to my computer. I get this error:

> **"Unable to access "128 GB Volume"** Error mounting/dev/sdc1 at/media/whooth2/3435-3234:unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

I have tried installing exFAT Support:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

This came up:

```
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse-exfat-utils
[sudo] password for wbooth2: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package exfat-fuse-exfat-utils
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils 
[sudo] password for wbooth2: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
  libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed 
  python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I've never used a SD reader before and I am not trained in using this language and programing.

Comment: This is a non-reproducible question caused by a typo error. `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse-exfat-utils` is incorrect. It should be `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` (with two packages instead of one).

Comment: This is what happened after your recommendation:

Comment: wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
[sudo] password for wbooth2: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed

Comment: Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Is your software updated? Please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and then try running `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` again. If that doesn't work open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for reading and search if there are any non-default software sources in it that are causing the unmet dependencies error.

Comment: ^^ first do this, and if that is still not working, run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as suggested and add the output here. And also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/142808

Comment: wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1 is to be installed
libpython2.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython2.7-minimal (= 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed

Comment: python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17-1~18.04) but 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ wbooth1055
wbooth1055: command not found
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ --fix-broken install
--fix-broken: command not found
wbooth2@wbooth2-desktop:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?